# Spring Data JPA use Pageable and Predicate filters on a @Query annotated repository method

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, filter, spring-data-jpa

I have a custom DTO :

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SaleCreditsSearchDto {
    private UUID ticketUuid;
    private UUID saleUuid;
    private String saleType;
    private Long ticketNumber;
    private LocalDateTime date;
    private Double amount;
    private Double saleTotalAmount;
    private String customerName;
    private String accountName;
}
```

And a query in my Repository that returns me a Page collection of these :

```
public interface SaleRepository
        extends CrudRepository<Sale, UUID> {

    @Query("SELECT new com.company.myproject.web.dto.SaleCreditsSearchDto("
            + "ticket.id, sale.id, sale.type, ticket.number, ticket.date, credit.amount, CONCAT(customer.lastname, ' ', customer.firstname), account.title)"
            + " FROM Sale sale"
            + " JOIN sale.ticket ticket"
            + " JOIN sale.credit credit"
            + " JOIN sale.customer customer"
            + " LEFT JOIN sale.account account"
            + " WHERE ticket.idEntity= :identity"
            + " AND ticket.date>= :datebegin"
            + " AND ticket.date< :dateend"
            + " AND ticket.state = 'FINISHED'"
            + " AND credit.initialAmount > 0"
            + " GROUP BY ticket.id, sale.id, credit.initialAmount, customer.lastname, customer.firstname, account.title")
    Page<SaleCreditsSearchDto> findTotalCredits(@Param("identity") String identity,
                                                @Param("datebegin") LocalDateTime dateBegin,
                                                @Param("dateend") LocalDateTime dateEnd,
                                                Predicate<SaleCreditsSearchDto> predicate,
                                                Pageable pageable);
}
```

But @Query methods does not accept more paramaters than @Param and a Pageable object, so I can't pass a Specification implementation, nor a Predicate.

What would you suggest to me to keep returning Page but with the possibility of filtering over some of the fields retrieved in the SELECT clause ?

Implement my own Repository method ? Passing filter in a @Query variable ? Have you practiced something similar before ? Thanks :)

Comment: I would suggest you implement a custom repository and do everything with CriteriaAPI. The problem in your example is that the JPQL query cannot be enhanced with CriteriaAPI predicate because it is executed as it is.

Comment: Ok that's what I was afraid of.. I will go ahead and write something custom with Criterias. thx for your answer :)